# Using SNMP4J to retrieve MIB info over TCP instead of UDP

Tags: tcp, udp, snmp, snmp4j, pdu

Using the SNMP4J library I am able to successfully retrieve information from multiple agents using SNMP over UDP. I am running into a situation where I need to retrieve information from an agent using SNMP over TCP. The SNMP4J library provides a DefaultTcpTransportMapping class to do this and I believe I've implemented it appropriately. Using Wireshark, I see response packets being returned from the agent running SNMP over TCP but I am getting null response PDUs. What other considerations do I need to address when implementing SNMP over TCP instead of UDP? Any help is greatly appreciated!

After a discussion with the board's manufacturer we've learned that the model for communication is SNMP over PMPP over TCP and I'm working on a custom SNMP4J transport to handle this model.

Comment: Is the SNMP agent listening on a TCP port?

Comment: Hi EJP, yes, TCP only on a port they've specified. They are not using UDP (port 161) for SNMP transport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to increase timeout value, TCP is slower than udp

```
UserTarget target = new UserTarget();
target.setTimeout(timeoutInMillis);
```

Comment: Tom, good thought. I did try several different combinations of longer intervals and more retries per session with no success.

Comment: Although there were many other adjustments necessary to the transport before we got it working, including building a custom transport since we eventually discovered that the model is TCP over PMPP, in the last steps it was a (drastic) increase in the timeout that we needed to get a response - thanks tomm!